# Javascript in usercontrol is not loading on kentico CMS

Tags: javascript, user-controls, kentico

I have usercontrol which is used in one of the projects. 
In this user control using javascript we are performing some operations.

I am using same usercontrol in kentico site. When i run the page that is using this usercontrol. There is no problem.
But the javascript used in the usercontrol is not loaded. And so if i try to perform the operation that uses Javascript nothing happens and in console i can see error as  "function undefined".

But if i copy that javascript locally in kentico CMSScripts folder and register that js in the page where user control is added, then everything is working perfectly.

How can i make js work without copying it locally .

Major problem is if usercontrol is a third party tool or the one given by client  and we don have access to javascript then, i cannot make the usercontrol run or work. 
Even if we have access to JS, It is not good to copy locally . because when there is any change in js , the change must be done on Usercontrol JS and Kentico Local JS which is not a good practice.

Please somebody help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you post a code sample of what is **generated**? without some code we can really only guess what is wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How do you register that script? Double check the generated path is correct and remote JS file can be loaded.

Also ensure the function declaration is before function call = remote file is loaded before you are trying to call a function from it. It can be done by adding the script tag to the HTML head.